# Receiving an "PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid property 'auto-delete' for queue 'test.queue' in vhost '/'" error message for Pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am attempting to declare a Queue on my RabbitMQ broker. I had no issue before this until I tried adding "auto_delete=True" parameter to the queue declaration. The Queue is meant to consume messsages from a fanout Exchange.

I have already deleted the Queue before declaring it again. I even tried renaming the Queue. Nevertheless, I keep receiving the same error "PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid property 'auto-delete' for queue 'test.queue' in vhost '/'". Below is my code for declaring the queue:

```
def setup_queue(self, queue_name):
        LOGGER.info('Declaring queue %s', queue_name)
        cb = functools.partial(self.on_queue_declareok, userdata=queue_name)
        self._channel.queue_declare(
            queue=queue_name,
            callback=cb,
            durable=True,
            auto_delete=True,
            arguments={"x-queue-type": "quorum", "x-max-length": MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't set `auto_delete=True` feature for Quorum queues.

See the features for more details:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html

Comment: Knew I set something wrong. Thank you!